# Ways to extend lap top battery life on Mavericks

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

What are some ways to extend lap top battery life on Mavericks? I've heard that disabling notification center via the terminal can help. I've also had a friend tell me that disabling window animations can make a difference; however, the effect from this seems like it wouldn't be noticeable. Are there any other ways?

*Disable Notification Center*

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist killall NotificationCenter
```

*Disable Window Animations*

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool false
```

Comment: Just using Mavericks is a pretty good way to extending your battery life. There are a lot of enhancements to reduce power consumption. If you really care, then the battery icon in the menu bar can show you a list of apps that are using “significant power”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Know when process is running wild**. You know that moment when the CPU suddenly run wild and your left palm feels the heat is increasing rapidly? That’s when you should open Activity Monitor, and see if there are any processes are consuming your battery life.

Sort by % CPU usage and you’ll always see the most consuming process on the top. Not all CPU consuming processes are bad, you might actually use some of them, like when you’re rendering videos, but usually browsers like Safari nor Chrome should be on the top of this list. The average CPU process rate should be around ±10% at most.

[image: Activity Monitor Preview]

As mentioned in the answer by Lauri, disabling Notification Center won’t have any real effect on the battery life. It only take a few seconds to show notification which won’t consume as much battery than playing music or watching videos.

So here are few tips to ensure you get the maximum battery life on MacBook:

1. Only run the apps you need. See if there are any background apps that run automatically without your permission. You can see the list of app in the **Users & Groups** and choose **Login Items**.
2. Brightness matters a lot. Keep it low unless you really it to view the screen.
3. Don’t bother to clear caches daily. They’re there to improve your Mac’s performance. Writing and reading from RAM, although not significant, exhausts battery life.
4. Use battery regularly. You can keep your MacBook plugged all day, but ensure to use it at least about 40% per day so the battery lifespan lasts longer.
5. It’s always nice to use MacBook in low temperature location. Heat hurts battery.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling Notification Center or disabling those animations won't have any real effect.

The best way to increase battery life is to turn down the brightness of the display. If for example a MacBook Air is idle and the display is set to maximum brightness, the display consumes about three times as much energy as all other components. You can see power consumption information from http://www.apple.com/environment/reports/:

```
                     off    sleep  idle with display off  idle with display at maximum brightness
13-inch MacBook Air  0.26W  0.69W  1.6W                   6.0W
15-inch MacBook Pro  0.33W  1.09W  8.53W                  15.6W
15-inch retina MBP   0.30W  0.87W  not mentioned          17.2W
```

You can use top to find processes with the highest accumulated (-ca) CPU use:

```
top -ca -o cpu
```

You can see the average CPU use of processes over a longer period by for example adding this line to crontab:

```
* * * * * ps -eco '\%cpu= comm='|sed $'s/^ *//;s/ /\t/'>>~/Desktop/cpu
```

Then run this later:

```
awk -F$'\t' '{a[$2]+=$1}END{for(i in a)print a[i],i}' ~/Desktop/cpu|sort -rn
```